# Use of uninitialized value $e2 in string eq & find: warning:

Tags: perl, ubuntu

Hopefully you can help a scientist to decipher whats wrong with the code I'm trying to run to clean up some NGS results. The Perl file itself comes from https://github.com/mtokuyama/ERVmap, though I am posting the code below for reference. The other Perl files in the package work just fine and, while I have built a passing ability to use the linux terminal, Perl is a little beyond me.

The linux terminal I'm using is currently running: Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS

This is the Perl code I'm trying to run using the following command line on linux as instructed by their GitHub page:

```
perl clean_htseq.pl ./ c c2 __
```

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
#$Id: run_clean_htseq.pl,v 1.2 2015/03/02 17:24:35 yk336 Exp $

#
# create pbs file
#

use warnings;
use strict;
use File::Basename;
use POSIX;

my $dir = shift;
my $e1 = shift;
my $e2 = shift;
my $stop = shift;

die "$e1 eq $e2" if ($e1 eq $e2);



my $find = "find $dir -name \"*${e1}\"";
my $out = `$find`;


my @files = split(/\n/, $out);
for my $f (@files) {
    my $o = $f;
    $o =~ s/${e1}$/$e2/;
    my $cmd = "./clean_htseq.pl $stop $f > $o";
    print "$cmd\n";
    system($cmd);
}
```

The first error that I had was that the _clean_htseq.pl_ wasn't found (line 30, already altered to solution) which i solved by adding the `./` in front of it and giving the software permission to use the script file.

My current issue with the code/command line is the following error:

```
Use of uninitialized value $e2 in string eq at ./clean_htseq.pl line 18.
find: warning: Unix filenames usually don't contain slashes (though pathnames do).  That means that '-name ‘*./SRR7251667.c’' will probably evaluate to false all the time on this system.  You might find the '-wholename' test more useful, or perhaps '-samefile'.  Alternatively, if you are using GNU grep, you could use 'find ... -print0 | grep -FzZ ‘*./SRR7251667.c’'.
```

This has been tracked down to the "__" at the end of the command line, while i'm sure this is supposed to mean something to the script I removed it and resulted in the following error:

```
Use of uninitialized value $stop in concatenation (.) or string at clean_htseq.pl line 30.
./clean_htseq.pl  ./SRR7251667.c > ./SRR7251667.c2
Use of uninitialized value $e1 in string eq at ./clean_htseq.pl line 18.
Use of uninitialized value $e2 in string eq at ./clean_htseq.pl line 18.
Use of uninitialized value $e1 in concatenation (.) or string at ./clean_htseq.pl line 18.
Use of uninitialized value $e2 in concatenation (.) or string at ./clean_htseq.pl line 18.
 eq  at ./clean_htseq.pl line 18.
```

An error occurs too when I remove the "." from "./" but it comes back with an error about not finding the _clean_htseq.pl_ file which is in the working directory.

Comment: The script seems to need 4 parameters, but the code runs it with only 2, $stop and $f. How is it supposed to work?

Comment: I'm having trouble finding an answer to that in the paper or its supplementary information. From what i understand it is supposed to do some post feature counting cleanup on next generation sequencing data. The file it is working on contains a list of approx 63k genes with the amount of times a sequence has aligned to that region next to it. This count can range from 0 to several thousand depending on how highly the gene is expressed.

Comment: I wonder if those underscores are used in a 'fill in the blank" sense.

Comment: Unknown, on their github page they list the command as:

"clean_htseq.pl ./output/cellular c c2 __"
so it would appear that they may be intended

Comment: I recommend emailing the author. Be aware that the script was written in 2015, but there was only one (!) issue - not sure how actively developed this code is now.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems to be here:

```
my $dir = shift;
my $e1 = shift;
my $e2 = shift;
my $stop = shift;
```

Outside of a subroutine, shift works on `@ARGV`—the array that holds the command line arguments. You `shift` four times, so you need four arguments:

```
perl clean_htseq.pl ./ c c2 __
```

You only seem to give it two, and `$stop` has no value (so you are giving it less than two):

```
./clean_htseq.pl $stop $f
```

You can't just remove arguments and hope things still work out. Likely you're going to have to look at the source to see what those things mean (which should motivate you as a scientist to use good variable names and document code—[Best Practices for Scientific Computing](https://journals.plos.org/plosbiology/article?id=10.1371/journal.pbio.1001745)).

A first step may be to set defaults. The [defined-or operator](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2010/10/set-default-values-with-the-defined-or-operator/) does well here:

```
use v5.10;

my $dir  = shift // 'default_dir';
my $e1   = shift // 'default_value';
my $e2   = shift // 'default_value';
my $stop = shift // 'default_value';
```

Or, you could just give up if there aren't enough arguments. An array in scalar context gives you the number of elements in the array (although it doesn't guarantee anything about their values):

```
die "Need four arguments!\n" unless @ARGV == 4;
```

There are various other improvements which would help this script, some of which I go through in the "Secure Programming Techniques" chapter in [Mastering Perl](https://www.mastering-perl.org). Taking unchecked user input and passing it to another program is generally not a good idea.

Comment: Thank you for the in depth explanation (and the grammar edits to the original post), i now have a better understanding of where/why the code is malfunctioning.